# Reduce file-clutter in git repository

Tags: git, garbage

I have been using `git-auto-commit-mode` on a little project I am working on, resulting in a total of 700 commits so far. As an undesirable side-effect, I now have a git repository, which is just 1,034kB in size, but consists of over 200 files - 50 times more than actual source code files.

Is there some way to cut down on such clutter?

I already tried

- `git repack`
- `git gc --aggressive`

Comment: If those files are part of previous commits which are still extant in your repository, then the files are not really a side-effect; they are part of the history.

Comment: Since you shouldn't be dealing with those files at all, only through the git client, I don't see the need to do anything about this at all. Those 200 files are the history of your repository, older versions of those files.

Comment: You can avoid creating unnecessary files (and commits) by getting into the habit of creating meaningful commits yourself, instead of auto-committing every *N* minutes. (If that is what git-auto-commit-mode does)

Comment: More importantly you should stop using "git-auto-commit-mode" because in addition to those files, your repository history will be a mess with nonsensical commits. You should instead learn how to use git properly and do isolated and meaningful commits. This will reduce the clutter in the history as well as reduce the number of files created in the .git repository folder.

Answer (score 1):

That files are related to older commits and they are present in the repo history. So what you can do is to create a new repository and copy all your files to a new one and make an initial commit. But then your history is lost. It's the easiest way if you really want a smaller repository.

But in your case i can't see a problem with 200 Files... and 1MB of disk space. That is nothing.

Comment: 700 commits with only 200 files.  That means most of those commits are empty.

Answer (score 1):

So first let's address scale.  You said 200 files is "50 times more than actual source code" - so you've set your expectations based on having a project with 4 files in the working tree, right?

By that measure, git is *always* going to have "a lot of files".

Now, the files git maintains go in the project's `.git` folder, so I don't really agree that it constitutes clutter.  (If you're seeing a bunch of files *outside* the `.git` folder, then some additional information is needed about what you're seeing and where.)

I just `init`ed a fresh repo, and it starts with 14 files before there's any content at all.  Adding a single commit with a single file adds another 9 files (refs, reflogs, the index, 3 actual objects in the history database, and some housekeeping material).  As you build a history, the thing that will likely grow the most is the database (`.git/objects`).

Now the commands you mention having tried... those allude to the point that git *can* store the database in "packed" format, which cuts down on the number of files.  That's always done for remote access (push/fetch), and over time history will generally "age into" a packed representation.  But for local access to frequently-accessed stuff, you're probably better off with the loose representation (which is why git isn't cooperating with your attempts to pack everything).

Rather than getting hung up on number of files in the `.git` directory (which you generally shouldn't interact with anyway), I'd worry a bit about the cleanliness of the commit history.

Having git auto-commit can be a way to make sure you never fail to capture a change, but it creates a low-value history.  If you're going to use it, then you need to periodically squash the generated commits into semantically meaningful commits (of the sort you would've made without auto-commit mode).

Over time, this will probably reduce the file count as well; but like I said, I really think that's beside the point.